# How to deserialize a non standard JSON request in Rails? (non-JSONAPI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json-deserialization, strong-parameters, actioncontroller

In a Rails app, I'm receiving a JSON request to track a `Order` model. I need to save all this to the DB.
I'm not sure how to handle this input into the controller.

The JSON request body is in this format:

```json
{
  "OrderID": "00023-00001",
  "OrderType": "Delivery",
  "DateTimes": {
    "DeliverDueDateTime": "2024/03/17 20:00:00"
  },
  "Area": {
    "Code": {
      "ZipCode": "1111",
      "AdditionalCodes": {
        "ZipCode": [
          "2111",
          "3111"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is a different format than what I'm used to (still new to this framework).

Most of the tutorials I found work with JSON keys in snake case, have either the `order` or `data` at the root, and don't contain nested data. Normally, I would do `params.require(:order).permit(:request_number, ...)`. But here it's a bit different.

This JSON is different because:

- it has nested keys
- doesn't have anything at the root
- has Pascal case keys

How should I handle this?

I checked the ActiveModel Serializer, but it doesn't seem to offer deserialization in this case. Unless I'm missing something.

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/deserialization.md

I tried things like:

```rb
params.permit(:OrderID, :OrderType, :Area)

params.permit(:OrderID, :OrderType).require(:Area).permit(:Code)

params.permit(:OrderID, :OrderType).require(:Area)

# ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: Area
```

Comment: `ActiveController::Parameters` doesn't change the case of the incoming parameter keys in any way and doesn't care. Using snake case is just the rails convention. It's really just a hash like object and you use `fetch` or `require` to pull out a given key and `permit` to slice it.

Comment: Permitting nested keys is done by passing hash arguments. What you will probably want to do though is create a object responsible for deserializing the request that's separate from your model.

Comment: This can be a plain old ruby object that takes the parameters as input and outputs a normalized version that corresponds to your internal representation. This avoids creating a tight coupling between your app and the crazy of the clients that connect to it.

Comment: Also ActiveModel::Serializers can actually be used to serialize/deserialize pretty much anything. The docs you have linked to is another gem that uses it for jsonapi.org. However it's not really going to make this job much simpler than a simple PORO.

Comment: What output format do you expect or need in your controller?